# Django hangs after trying to init server on OSX El Capitan

Tags: python, django, macos

I'm trying to run a Django project on OSX El Capitan, MySQL 5.7.9 for OSX 10.9 (no download for 10.11). I'm using a virtual environment. I installed all dependencies using "pip", on that virtual environment. This project works on other machines. The only thing I changed is the `local.py` file, in order to link the proper database. I'm trying to run the server with the command:

```
python manage.py runserver 127.0.0.1:9000
```

When I type that on the main Django directory, the console hangs - there is no error or success message, it just hangs there indefinitely. How can I troubleshot/debug to locate the cause of this problem?

Comment: I am sorry, I mistyped that on the question. Both `localhost:9000` and `127.0.0.1:9000` give the same result (i.e., nothing). Isn't it possible to run django verbosely? At least so I have an idea of where is the issue?

Comment: You can use the [`--verbosity`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-option---verbosity) option: `python manage.py runserver --verbosity 3 localhost:9000`

Answer (score 1):

I didn't see @Alasdair comment in time, so I used the `ipdb` library to trace the program execution. I used:

```
import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()
```

To set a breakpoint on `manage.py`. I then attempted to run the server again. I used `c` to navigate to the breakpoint and `n` to step through the program flow until the program froze. I then repeated that process by using `s` instead of `n` on the point the freeze happened. I also updated the breakpoint position sometimes, as not to need to go through the whole execution all over again every time.

After navigating all the way through the Django libs, to my own project model's, back to a Django class's constructors responsible for doing lazy DB queries, I figured it should be a database-related issue. I then downgraded MySQL to version `5.6.27` by installing the `.DMG` package available the official site. Doing so solved the issue.